# How to create a route using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, routes

I am trying to create a route between two places, explicitly noted in the html file.  I tried to copy the google documentation as best as I can, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Breadcrumbz</title>
    <style>
            #map {
                    height: 400px;
                    width: 100%;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>MAP!?!</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button onclick="calcRoute()">Click me</button>
    <script>
            var directionsDisplay;
            var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            function initMap() {
                    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
                    var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 7,
                            center: chicago
                    }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            }

            function calcRoute(){
                    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
                    var end = new new google.maps.LatLng(37.3229978, -122.0321823);

                    var request = {
                            origin: start,
                            destination: end,
                            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                            if(status == 'OK') {
                                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                            } else {
                            }
                    });
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHqgK27rLZ-mWuh2Ha1wPCkMGVs0MDoQI&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typos in your code. Look at the javascript console:

- `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a constructor`
  (extra `new` on this line: `var end = new new google.maps.LatLng(37.3229978, -122.0321823);`)
- `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`
  (`map` is local to the `initMap` function, needs to be passed into `calcRoute` or a global)
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: directionsService is not defined`
  (typo on this line: `var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();`, should be `directionsService`, not directionService`)

Then it works:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gjak3s2h/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initMap() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: chicago
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute(map);
}

function calcRoute(map) {
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3229978, -122.0321823);
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert("directions request failed, status=" + status)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```